# Re-authenticating User Credentials Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wish to re-authenticate a user prior to allowing them to change their login information. However, due to the recent Firebase update, I found the documentation rather unhelpful. Using [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) I produced the following authenticateUser() function.

```
func authenticateUser()
{
    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    var credential: FIRAuthCredential

    //prompt user to re-enter info

    user?.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential, completion: { (error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            self.displayAlertMessage("Error reauthenticating user")
        }
        else
        {
            //user reauthenticated successfully
        }
    })
}
```

However, I am unsure what to do with the credential variable of type FIRAuthCredential, in order to re-authenticate the user. The documentation for this class can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_auth_credential#properties).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Getting the `FIRAuthCredential` object depends on what provider you want to use to reauthenticate.

#### Email:

```
let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
```

#### Facebook:

```
let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
```

#### Twitter:

```
let credential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(withToken: session.authToken, secret: session.authTokenSecret)
```

#### Google:

```
let authentication = user.authentication
let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
```

Comment: What do I put into the email and password fields?

Comment: Note that as of 2020 it's slightly updated to:

`var credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)`

Comment: @Shredder2794 OMG Thanks so much!!! I have been looking for this for a long time! :)

Answer (score 12):

In Swift 4 and latest firebase 4 the names have changed a bit, but the principle still remains. For your convenience:

```
    let eMail = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: "some@email.com", password: "somepassword")
    let fb = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: "xxx")
    let g = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: "xxx", accessToken: "xxx")
    ...

    Auth.auth().currentUser?.reauthenticate(with: eMail, completion: {
        [weak self]
        (error) in
        ...
    })
```

Comment: let authentication = user.authentication is missing, how can we get that HixField ?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I need to change email address for google accounts. I am using currentUser.updateEmail() function which requires currentUser.reauthenticate() However I can not get GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication to get IdToken and AccessToken. GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser returns nil. I am using FirebaseAuthUI for login & register. And my current user = Auth.auth().currentUser does not have authentication property

Comment: I am not using the firebaseui, sorry

Comment: what about phone number reauthentication?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) is currently outdated. Here is the correct way to handle `reauthenticate`.

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

user?.reauthenticate(with: credential, completion: { (result, error) in
   if let err = error {
      //..read error message             
   } else {
      //.. go on              
   }
})
```

Comment: How can I get the email and password for the cred?

Comment: @Clint I think you are asking about `EmailAuthProvider` which you can use `let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: "example@email.com", password: "myPassword")`.

Comment: yes I apologize that is correct. Am I suppose to actually enter something in the Email: “email” and password: “ password”?

Comment: @Clint  If your app requires a login, this would be the user's email and password. How you save/get the user's info is up to you. Using `reauthenticate` assumes you already have authenticated the user in the past.  So you should already have the email and password, otherwise you need to look into how to authenticate not `reauthenticate `.

Comment: Oh I see, So I already saved the users email to the database however I never save passwords.. So thats a problem. The only way for me to get the users current password for reauthentication is to save the users current password? ( I want to avoid having them enter their old password)

Comment: @Clint you may need ask the user for them again or start using `NSUserDefaults` to save user passwords locally.

Comment: Do you mind helping me with my question, you definitely know how re authentication works. I can’t link it since I’m on my phone. But if you visit my profile it’s my most recent question..