# How do I grab credential values for re authentication? (Question updated)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to allow users to change their email or password. I did some research on how re authentication work, most of the questions I had were answered however when creating the `credential` how do I grab the users email / password in the `.credentialWithEmail(email, password: password)` section? I'm not sure what to enter in those fields.

When I take a look at the quick help tab, it explains the Parameters:

**email
The user's email address.
password
The user's password.**

Here is the code

```swift
   let credential = FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credentialWithEmail(email, password: password)

  func updateEmail() {



        guard let updatedEmail = self.updatedEmail else { return }

        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        // re authenticate the user
        user?.reauthenticate(with: credential, completion: { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // An error happened.
                print(error._code)
                self.handleError(error)
            } else {
                guard self.emailChanged == true else { return }

                user?.updateEmail(to: self.emailTextField.text!, completion: { (error) in
                                        if let error = error {
                                            self.handleError(error)
                                        } else {
                                            print("Email Change Success")
                                            USER_REF.child(currentUid).child("email").setValue(updatedEmail) { (err, ref) in

                                                 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }

    }

        )}



    }
    )}
```

Comment: Assign some non-nil value to `credential` before force-unwrapping it.

Comment: @Kamran honestly I don’t really don’t how to work with Credential. How do I get the users email and password to re authenticate them?

Comment: You have the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253185/re-authenticating-user-credentials-swift).

Comment: Oh I see. I’m not quite sure how to get the email and password variables though..

Comment: There is another option as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-authenticating User Credentials Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253185/re-authenticating-user-credentials-swift)

Comment: @Kamran Thank you for those links, I have updated the question better I hope it helps.

Comment: This is pretty clearly outlined in the guide. [Reauthenticating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user). Did you follow those instructions? *When this happens, re-authenticate the user by getting new sign-in credentials from the user and passing the credentials to reauthenticate*

Comment: @Jay so if a user wants to change their password. Am I reauthenticating them with the new password or email they entered? It says re authenticate the user by getting new sign in credentials and pass it. So if u have the an email text field and password TextField, and the user wants to only change the email. Would I get an error because the password TextField is empty?

Comment: Again, that's covered in the docs. If the password is being changed and the user has not recently signed in, the change attempt will fail, which would mean it's not changed. You will need to re-authenticate them in order to make the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking why you can't get the email or password after you set `FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider`, it is because it is set only. There is no function to retrieve email/password after you set `FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider`. Firebase does not have a way to retrieve set passwords from their `Auth` class. The user email can be retrieved with `let userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email`

You may need to redesign you code to allow the app to save passwords locally using `NSUserDefaults` or simply make the user reenter them.

Comment: Thank you @temp_   also for  clarification, can I have the user re enter their old password first then enter their new one?